# Getting list of names from id array for facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am looking to grab the names of facebook users from an array of about 100 ids and store in php variables.  Is there a way to do it without making api calls or using curl for each id in a loop?

Comment: "Is there a way to do it without making api calls" --- uhm, how to retrieve the data if not by performing API request? Magically?

Answer (score 4):

Yes:

https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=id1,id2,...,idX&fields=name

Answer (score 0):

You can do [this](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=336359#p336359):

You can run an FQL query on the 'user' table to get their name.

Here are a few links for more information:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/